# From two-columns portrait to one-column landscape: Force the text and the page number (in the landscape mode) to the left margin

Tags: margins, two-column, alignment, landscape, justification

Please help me force the text `Hola` and the page number `2` to the top-left margin of the rotated page in the next code.

Note: I am working with a two-column portrait document and need a temporary change to a one-column landscape, with the `Hola` text located on the top-left border.

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

% Packages for various functionalities
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text; you can remove this in your actual document
\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{caption} % For captions
\usepackage{authblk} % For author affiliations
\usepackage{longtable} % For long tables
\usepackage{pdflscape} % For landscape pages
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % Adjust margins as desired
\usepackage{showframe} % To display page borders
\usepackage{geometry} %to change page margins
 \geometry{
 letterpaper,
 left=10mm,
 top=10mm,
 bottom=10mm,
 right=10mm
 }
 
% Title and authors
\title{Your Title Here}
\author[1]{Author One}
\author[2]{Author Two}
\affil[1]{Affiliation One}
\affil[2]{Affiliation Two}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
% ... (Sections and content here)


\begin{landscape}
\newgeometry{margin=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm} % Adjust margins for landscape page
\clearpage %needed for next command
\onecolumn %reset to one column mode


Hola

\clearpage %needed for next command
\twocolumn %reset to two-column mode
\restoregeometry %return to initial page margins
\end{landscape}


\section{Discussion}
% ... (Remaining content here)

\end{document}
```

The current bad outcome looks like this:

[image]

I want the outcome like the one below (to the left):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

---

**Edit on Thursday, January 4, 2024, 22:24 (UTC +0000):**

**Issue 1:**

In [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange Chat Ulrike Fischer pointed out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64922008#64922008) that
with `\newgeometry` of the package **geometry** you need to apply the `onecolumn`-option although switching to one-column-mode via `\onecolumn`.

**Issue 2:**

The typeblock is the box holding the text of a page of the document.
(Not the headers/footers, not the margin notes.)

But in LaTeX no parameters/lengths `\typeblockwidth`/`\typeblockheight` are introduced.

Instead, each of `\textwidth` and `\textheight` is to determine two things:

In any case

- `\textwidth` is to determine the horizontal extension of the typeblock.
- `\textheight` is to determine the vertical extension of the typeblock.

In case text within the typeblock is justified horizontally

- `\textwidth` is to also determine the maximum length of lines of text which fit into the typeblock.
- `\textheight` is to also determine the amount of space available for placing lines of text atop each other within the typeblock.

In case text within the typeblock is justified vertically

- `\textwidth` is to also determine the amount of space available for placing lines of text atop each other within the typeblock.
- `\textheight` is to also determine the maximum length of lines of text which fit into the typeblock.

Within the environment `landscape` of the package **lscape**<sup>1</sup> `\textheight` is changed to determine the amount of space available for within the typeblocks of pages placing lines of text atop each other while these lines within the typeblocks of pages are justified vertically.

This change disregards the fact that `\textheight` in any case - no matter if text within the typeblock is justified horizontally or vertically - is to determine the vertical extension of the typeblock.

I.e., while the environment `landscape` of the package **lscape**<sup>1</sup> is in effect, `\textheight` does not determine the vertical extension of the typeblock any more.

But with the routine `\ShowFramePicture` of the package **showframe** for drawing the frames it is (correctly, imho) assumed that `\textheight` in any case determines the vertical extension of the typeblock.

Thus **lscape**'s<sup>1</sup>  modification of `\textheight` needs  to be undone before drawing a set of frames via `\ShowFramePicture` takes place.

So I decided to have `\ShowFramePicture` redefined within the `landscape`-environment to reset `\textheight` (only) within the local scope which is in effect while drawing the frames.

<sup>1</sup>The package **pdflscape** internally loads **lscape** and modifies the environment `landscape` of the package **lscape** so that to each page shipped out to the .pdf-file while the environment `landscape` is in effect a directive for the pdf-viewer is added to display on the screen this page rotated by an angle of 90 degrees. This directive only affects how the page is shown on the computer screen/on the display used for viewing the .pdf-file. This directive actually does not affect TeX's typesetting work. It affects the "displaying work" of the program used for viewing the pdf-file. Although with pages typeset and shipped out while the environment `landscape` was in effect lines of text of the typeblocks are justified vertically, you don't need to tilt your head to the left or to the right for reading them on the screen/display as those pages are displayed rotated by 90 degrees so that you can read them by looking at the screen/display of your computer from the left to the right.

---

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn, letterpaper]{article}

% Packages for various functionalities
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text; you can remove this in your actual document
\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{caption} % For captions
\usepackage{authblk} % For author affiliations
\usepackage{longtable} % For long tables
\usepackage{pdflscape} % For landscape pages
\usepackage{geometry} %to change page margins
\usepackage{showframe} % To display page borders

\geometry{
 letterpaper,
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=20mm,
 right=20mm
}

\newcommand\savetextheight{}%

% Title and authors
\title{Your Title Here}
\author[1]{Author One}
\author[2]{Author Two}
\affil[1]{Affiliation One}
\affil[2]{Affiliation Two}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
%... (Sections and content here)
\lipsum[1-8]

\onecolumn %reset to one column mode
\newgeometry{onecolumn, margin=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm}% Adjust margins for landscape page

\edef\savetextheight{\number\textheight\space sp\relax}%
\begin{landscape}%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ShowFramePicture{%
  \begingroup
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %  \textheight is modified within the landscape-environment because the box holding the text
    %  is rotated. But the frames around the text are drawn on the sheet of paper, which during
    %  typesetting is not rotated (, although pdflscape tells pdf-viewers to display it rotated).
    %  Thus modification of \textheight is to be undone while drawing the frames:
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \textheight=\savetextheight
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \ShowFrameColor\linethickness{\ShowFrameLinethickness}%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
      \framebox(\paperwidth,\paperheight){}}%
    \AtTextLowerLeft{%
      \framebox(\textwidth,\textheight){}}%
    \AtTextUpperLeft{%
      \put(0,\headsep){%
        \framebox(\textwidth,\headheight){}}}%
    \AtTextLowerLeft{%
      \put(0,-\footskip){%
        \line(1,0){\textwidth}}}%
    \AtTextLowerLeft{%
      \SF@tempdima=\textwidth\advance\SF@tempdima\marginparsep
      \if@twoside
        \ifodd\c@page\else
          \if@mparswitch
            \SF@tempdima=-\marginparsep\advance\SF@tempdima-\marginparwidth
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
      \put(\SF@tempdima,0)%
        {\framebox(\marginparwidth,\textheight){}}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\noindent Hola \lipsum[1-18]
\clearpage
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{landscape}%

\twocolumn
\restoregeometry %return to initial page margins

\section{Discussion}
% ... (Remaining content here)
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

| [image] |
| --- |

Comment: Wonderful explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

The following MWE (Minimal Working Example) reproduce your second image in question:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,
            margin=1in]{geometry} % Adjust margins as desired

\usepackage{afterpage} % For landscape pages
\usepackage{pdflscape} % For landscape pages

% Packages for various functionalities
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text; you can remove this in your actual document
\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{caption} % For captions
\usepackage{authblk} % For author affiliations
\usepackage{longtable} % For long tables
                    

% Title and authors
\title{Your Title Here}
\author[1]{Author One}
\author[2]{Author Two}
\affil[1]{Affiliation One}
\affil[2]{Affiliation Two}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]

\afterpage{%
    \clearpage
\newgeometry{margin=20mm} % Adjust margins for landscape page
\onecolumn              % reset to one column mode
    \begin{landscape}

Hola, landscape here!

\lipsum[1-3]

    \end{landscape}
\restoregeometry %return to initial page margins
\twocolumn %reset to two-column mode
            }% end afterpage          
\lipsum[6]

\section{Discussion}
\lipsum[7-13]

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is not entirely clear, where you like to have page numbers. So far I left them as it is default positioned (centered in foot).

In cases, that you like to have page number at some other place, you need to define new header/footer styles, for example with use `fancyhdr` package. For example, to preamble add

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\fancypagestyle{LandScape}%
{%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead[L]{\thepage}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
```

and before `\begin{landscape}` in document body insert

```
\pagestyle{LandScape}
```

Resulted page style is:

[image]

**Edit:**

- It is not clear why you define `\newgeometry` when it has the same settings as other document (portrait oriented) pages geometry. In such cases I wouldn't use it, i.e. in your case I would simple dropout it.
- If drawing page layout frames correctly on all pages is your main concern, that you should stick with  @Ulrich Diez proposed solution (+1).
- His solution, adopted to my original answer, with a wee bit modificated code is shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,
            margin=1in]{geometry} % Adjust margins as desired
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.5pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}     % For dummy text; in actual document
                        % you can/should remove it

\newcommand\savetextheight{}%
\edef\savetextheight{\number\textheight\space sp\relax}%
\makeatletter%
\renewcommand\ShowFramePicture{%
    \textheight=\savetextheight
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\ShowFrameColor\linethickness{\ShowFrameLinethickness}%
\AtTextLowerLeft{% text box
  \framebox(\textwidth,\textheight){}}%
\AtTextUpperLeft{% page header
  \put(0,\headsep){%
    \framebox(\textwidth,\headheight){}}}%
\AtTextLowerLeft{% page margin
  \put(0,-\footskip){%
    \line(1,0){\textwidth}}}%
\AtTextLowerLeft{%  when document is twoside
  \SF@tempdima=\textwidth\advance\SF@tempdima\marginparsep
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page\else
      \if@mparswitch
        \SF@tempdima=-\marginparsep\advance\SF@tempdima-\marginparwidth
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \put(\SF@tempdima,0)%
    {\framebox(\marginparwidth,\textheight){}}%
                }% end of twoside
                    }% end of \renewcommand
\makeatother

% Packages for various functionalities
\usepackage{afterpage}  % For remove empty space on page before 
                        % landscape page with text after it
\usepackage{pdflscape}  % For landscape pages
\usepackage{graphicx}   % For including images
\usepackage{caption}    % For captions
\usepackage{authblk}    % For author affiliations
\usepackage{longtable}  % For long tables


% Title and authors
\title{Your Title Here}
\author[1]{Author One}
\author[2]{Author Two}
\affil[1]{Affiliation One}
\affil[2]{Affiliation Two}

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]

\afterpage{%
    \clearpage
\onecolumn                  % reset to one column mode
\begin{landscape}%
Hola, landscape here!

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{longtable}[htb]{|p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
\caption{Longtable: width = \texttt{textwidth}} \\
    \hline
\lipsum[66] \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}[htb]{|p{\dimexpr\textheight-2\tabcolsep}|}
\caption{Longtable: width = \texttt{textheight}} \\
    \hline
\lipsum[66] \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}[htb]{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
\caption{Longtable: width = \texttt{linewidth}} \\
    \hline
\lipsum[66] \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}%
\twocolumn
        }% end \afterpage


\section{Discussion}
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this answer. Easier for latex newbies, like me. Thank you!

Comment: I used `\newgeometry` because the margins in portrait (1 cm) are different than in landscape (2 cm)

Comment: @alexyshr, you are right. Copying your MWE it seems that I made some erroneous editing. I will correct my answer accordingly ASAP.